# One post in two archives

Tags: php, wordpress

Well, this one is getting me quite frustrated. I have multiple custom post types (CPT). Most of them have an archive. Now I have a ctp called `Portfolio` and a cpt called `recent work`.

What I would like is to have both ctp's show up in the archives-[slug].php pages. BUT in one archive the link should be `/portfolio/page-name` and in the other it should be `/recent-work/page-name`.

Both pages would show the same content only the archive slug would be different. I don't want to have to create double content.

Does anyone know if this is possible using Wordpress and how I can achieve this...

As Gavin Thomas said, use categories (well in my case custom taxonomies). This is my loop code:

```
<?php $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'portfolio',
            'posts_per_page'=> -1,
            'orderby' => 'ID',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                'taxonomy' => 'event-type',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'corporate-events'
                        )
                    )
                );

                $products = new WP_Query( $args );
                    if( $products->have_posts() ) {
                        while( $products->have_posts() ) {
                            $products->the_post();
        ?>

        <?php   $naam =     get_field('naambedrijf');
                $soort =    get_field('soort_uitje');
                $foto =     get_field('flickr_fotoset'); ?>

            <div class="col s6 m4 l4">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h2 class="truncate" style="line-height:20px;"><?php echo $naam; ?></h2>
                            <small class="truncate" style="color:#222;"><?php echo $soort; ?></small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumb">
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                            the_post_thumbnail();
                        } ;?>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>



        <?php
            }
                }
                    else {
                        echo 'There seems to be a problem, please try searching again or contact customer support!';
                    } ?>
```

The items under the ctp are displayed using this code, but the permalink is still `/portfolio/page-name` and not `/category-slug/page-name`. How do I go about this?

Comment: It's possible if you put the post into a category. You could then have `/category-{slug}/page-name`.

Comment: Will this work for custom taxonomies as well? Please see my update in my OP.

Comment: Yes it would - recently accomplished something very similar - just create a category-{slug}.php page (as you would with the archive) and add each of the post types to the wp_query array - e.g. `post_type' => array('portfolio','recent_work','etc.'), 'cat' => 1`

Comment: Shoudn't that be a taxonomy-{slug}.php page in this case? Or would the taxonomy term work like a category-{slug}.php page?

Comment: I believe taxonomy-slug would work too, but it all depends on your WP_query. e.g. in your category-slug.php page, you would define what post types you'd be pulling from.

Comment: Ok, just lets see if I understand correct. I got a category page named `category-corporate-events.php`. This is a custom category type of `event-type`. This will keep the permalink `portfolio/page-name` because the ctp is `portfolio`. 

So if I were to use the normal categories "thing" of Wordpress and create a category named `corporate-events` there I could pull the data from that category and display it in different categories whilst only the `/category/` changes and not the page name. Because at this moment I'm not able to create the query to get the categories...

Comment: I can get the data from the category ONLY if I use the post_type as well. Or else it doesn't display any posts. But this also changes the link to `/portfolio/` and not to the category name...

Comment: Yes - that's why you put each post_type into the array, like my example above.

Comment: Ok, this is my query now: `<?php $args = array(
   'post_type' => array('portfolio','recent_work'),
      'cat_ID' => '23',
      'posts_per_page'=> -1
      );

          $products = new WP_Query( $args );
              if( $products->have_posts() ) {
                  while( $products->have_posts() ) {
                      $products->the_post();
  ?>` 

Please don't mind the products because I just copied an other query from somewhere else.

Comment: As long as that is in your category-slug.php page - it should all be fine.

Comment: Ok... it is.. Let me just work about a bit... thanks for your help.